# Intermixing Spring Security OAuth2 and Jose4j

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, jose4j

I was wondering (before I try implemnting somethign along this path) about an approach.
Lets say I have a complete working OAuth2 system (using spring boot and spring cloud but not spring cloud security).  This, so far has worked quite well and supports several different grant types.
What I am interested in is the possibility of hand creating the JWT in certain special cases and then utilizing this token with spring security.
I looked at jose4j and it seems like i should be able to use this in place of the authorization server portion of the system.  Note that the goal of this was where i had to create a token that would have normally be generated by the authorization server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [`TokenEnhancer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenEnhancer.html) or in particular [`JwtAccessTokenConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.html). The latter one also provides encode/decode methods you can overwrite to use custom libraries for  encoding/decoding of tokens or to add custom properties.

Note: Make sure to check the signature of the tokens!